# JAVA gwt - saving info after refreshing page

Tags: java, gwt, window, refresh

At the moment , im working with java gwt and i stopped studdenly because one problem occured. I want that my information (for example string) will save after refresh button is clicked.

```
    // user enters something in TextArea textArea1 object

    Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
                    public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent closingEvent) {
                   //maybe there is a function or what                      
                   pleaseSaveInfomation(textArea1);
                    }
                });
```

I tried this , but i know how to implement it correctly to my source code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220746/5010218

The last(worst) chance is to store data from textArea in file.txt , after refreshing i could read info from file and thats all. But maybe GWT has a specific handler/method/class or what to handle this.

Thats for your opinion and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can easily overcome it with this.

```
import com.google.gwt.storage.client.Storage;
  private Storage stockStore = null;
  stockStore = Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported();
```

Please read documentation

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html#UsingStorage

Answer (score 0):

When a browser close a window (because of a refresh, or the user has closed the window, changed the url, etc), a script is not allowed to prevent this action. It's not specific to GWT.

However, you can suggest to the browser-agent to show a confirmation to the user. You can do this with the `message` property of the closing event.

In GWT:

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
   public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent closingEvent) {
      closingEvent.setMessage("Confirm ?"); 
   }
});
```

You shouldn't rely on this event to store your data, as a lot of condition can prevent you to do this. You should maybe periodically store a draft to the local-storage or to the server.

Comment: so what is the best option to store data after refresh? Please send link or smt to start with

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store your data in `sessionStorage`. In GWT, this the `Storage` class.